# Bash to find missing file

Tags: bash, find

I'm counting files in a photos folder:

```
% find . -type f | wc -l
   22188
```

Then I'm counting files per extension:

```
% find . -type f | sed -n 's/..*\.//p' | sort | uniq -c
 268 AVI
14983 JPG
  61 MOV
   1 MP4
 131 MPG
   1 VOB
  21 avi
   1 jpeg
6602 jpg
  12 mov
  20 mp4
  74 mpg
  12 png
```

The sum of that is 22187, not 22188. So I thought it could be a file without extension:

```
% find . -type f ! -name "*.*"
```

But the result was empty. Maybe a file starting with `.`:

```
% find . -type f ! -name "?*.*"
```

But also empty. How can I find out what that file is?

I'm on macOS 10.15.

Comment: I'd try saving the output to a file at various stages in the pipeline (especially just before & after the `sed -n` step), and compare them to see where the total count is changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command should find the missing file:

```
comm -3 <(find . -type f | sort) <(find . -type f | sed -n '/..*\./p' | sort)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a file with an embedded carriage return (or linefeed)?

Would be curious to see what this generates:

```
find . -type f | grep -Eiv '\.avi|\.jpg|\.mov|\.mp4|\.mpg|\.vob|\.avi|\.jpeg|\.png'
```

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try:

```
find . -type f -name $'*\n*'
```

It will pick up filenames which contain newline character.
The `ANSI-C quoting` is supported by bash-3.2.x or so on MacOS.